# Branch io deeplink not working in Test environment (Working in LIVE with same code)

Tags: ios, iphone, branch.io, deeplink

Branch io deeplink has stopped working for my app in test environment since today morning.
Though it has stopped only in test environment and is working in the LIVE environment (with the exact same code), I want the test environment also to be working fine so that I am confident in uploading my build.
Searched but could not find anything related to this.

(It was working till last week and I haven't done any code or setting change since a long time)

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Alex from Branch here: could you clarify exactly which part of the deep linking process is not working as expected? Might it be related to Universal Links?

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply @AlexBauer. Got an email reply from your team, have posted as my answer.

Comment: excellent! That was going to be my message also, but our support is pretty awesome :)

Comment: @AlexBauer Is it still the case that the Testing environment is not reliable? And I should only expect links to work properly in Live? -thanks

Comment: @vikzilla assuming you've signed up any time in the last year and have `app.link` URLs (rather than `bnc.lt`), the test environment has been updated and you shouldn't be seeing any issues now!

Comment: @AlexBauer Thanks, yes I believe it was because my domains were incorrect in Capabilities.

Comment: @vikzilla That would do it! Glad everything is working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had mailed the Branch team. Got a very quick reply. Here it is:

> Thanks for writing in. So sorry for the issue here - this is because Apple recently limited the size of AASA files with the release of 9.3.1, and we therefore had to remove our test schemes from the AASA file. We're recommending that everyone test with their live schemes if using bnc.lt. Alternatively, you could [set up a custom domain with your test scheme](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/advanced/ios/#using-a-custom-domain-or-subdomain). Either way, rest assured that your live scheme will still work in production.

Also, they don't seem to have a near future plan to re-add the test schemes to the AASA files so they recommend us testing with our live Dashboard or using a custom domain for our test dashboard.